# Missing method exception while InvokeMember

Tags: f#, com, missingmethodexception

I'm creating a COM component in F#. The component is expected to be used from scripting.

The component code:

```
namespace WebUIPlugin

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<Guid("BAEF0C5B-EFA5-4868-8342-7A1E6F8F7AF4")>]
type IPlugin =
    [<DispId(1)>]
    abstract OpenFormFromFile : path:string -> unit

[<Guid("8D71E2DB-D718-4595-B856-58D14EEAEBB2");
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None);
ComVisible(true)>]
type Plugin = class
  new () = {}

  interface IPlugin with
    member this.OpenFormFromFile(path) =
      let showWindow =
        let window = Window()
        window.Show

      UI.spawn showWindow |> ignore
  end
end
```

I'm registering it with `regasm /codebase Plugin.dll` and it works well from scripting `cscript test.js`.

test.js is following:

```js
var obj = new ActiveXObject("WebUIPlugin.Plugin");
obj.OpenFormFromFile("");
```

It even stops on breakpoint in `OpenFormFromFile`. So good so far.

Unfortunately, I cannot make it work from F#/C#:

```
let objectType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WebUIPlugin.Plugin")
let handler = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType)
objectType.InvokeMember("OpenFormFromFile", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, handler, [|""|]) |> ignore
```

```cs
var objectType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WebUIPlugin.Plugin");
dynamic handler = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
objectType.InvokeMember("OpenFormFromFile", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, handler, new object[]{""});
```

The code throws exception:

> An unhandled exception of type `System.MissingMethodException` occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Attempted to access a missing member.

Everything (component, test C# and F# projects, regasm, cscript) is either in x64 or x86 consistently. With the same result - WSH script works, .NET assembly does not.

Comment: Can you find out which method it thinks is missing? (The most common case for this kind of error is when you're loading F# code referencing one version of `FSharp.Core.dll` in an application that references another version of `FSharp.Core.dll` - though it sounds like this might not be the case here..)